# Sql Server Triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table which have 4 fields.

```
Col1 Guid Primary-Key (FK to another table)
Col2 Guid Primary-Key (FK to another table)
Col3 Int Primary-Key
Col4 Int
```

Now i want to do this: when a new record inserted by user which have same value as a record exist before on the table like below:

There was this Record:

```
X Y Z 2
```

New record

```
X Y Z 3
```

Update existing record to below:

```
X Y Z 5
```

and also prevent from inserting duplicate record. I wrote very basic trigger. now help me to complete this. Thanks in advance. ;)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Tbl].[TriggerName] 
ON  [dbo].[Tbl] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [dbo].[Tbl]
SET [dbo].[Tbl].[Col4] += [Inserted].[Col4]
From [dbo].[Tbl] INNER JOIN [Inserted] ON [dbo].[Tbl].[Col1] = [Inserted].[Col1] AND
                                          [dbo].[Tbl].[Col2] = [Inserted].[Col2]
WHERE [dbo].[Tbl].[Col3] = [Inserted].[Col3];
//How to prevent from inserting duplicate record?
END
```

Comment: If your primary key is `(col1, col2, col3)`, the user will never be able to insert `X Y Z 3` when `X Y Z 2` already exists. That would violate your primary key.

Comment: @Joe Yes you're right, before to do this i created this primary keys to prevent from duplicate, but now i want to update record which exist into the table, so after solving this issue i'm going to remove primary keys or expand to four cols ;)

Comment: @Sadegh: Why are you trying to put this in a trigger at all? Why can't you test for existence in your code and update/insert as appropriate at that point.

Comment: @Joe Well i'm going to convert some part of my business-logic's from code to db-side to have more integrity!

Comment: @Sadegh: My previous suggestion would still apply. Call a stored procedure from the code side that will do the `if exists...update... else insert...` logic.

Comment: @Joe Also is there any performance gain or not for doing this by trigger or code?

Comment: "now help me to complete this." - As you wish, My Master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to consolidate my comments into an answer.

I would avoid using a trigger in this case. I believe your best approach is to write a stored procedure that you can call from your code. That stored procedure would perform the `if exists... update... else insert...` logic.

Comment: Dear Joe, i really doesn't use from any sp in my app, i use DLINQ to doing anything! and because this i'm going to solve my problem by trigger ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 you can use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Joe Stefanelli said, the BEST approach is to replace the direct inserts into the table by having an insert-or-update stored proc and revoking the INSERT perms on the table.

However, if you are dead set on the trigger, try adding the following to the trigger

```
DELETE [dbo].[Tbl]
From [dbo].[Tbl] INNER JOIN [Inserted] ON [dbo].[Tbl].[Col1] = [Inserted].[Col1] AND
                                          [dbo].[Tbl].[Col2] = [Inserted].[Col2]
WHERE [dbo].[Tbl].[Col3] = [Inserted].[Col3] AND [dbo].[Tbl].[Col4] = [Inserted].[Col4];
```